# Laravel 8 pass data from blade to Vue 3

Tags: javascript, laravel, undefined, laravel-blade, vuejs3

I try to pass data from Laravel blade to Vue with props and I get undefined in console.
I tried also

```
<example-component :course="{{ $course }}"></example-component>
<example-component course="{{!! $course !!}}"></example-component>
```

**index.blade.php**

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
    <div id="app">
    
    </div>
    
    <example-component course="{{ $course }}"></example-component>

    <script src="{{asset('js/course/app.js')}}"></script>
@endsection
```

**app.js**

```
import { createApp } from 'vue';
import App from './components/App.vue'
import router from '../../router'
createApp(App).use(router).mount("#app")
```

**App.vue**

```
<template>
{{ course }}
</template>

<script>
export default {
props: ['course'],
mounted() {
console.log(this.course)
}
}
</script>
```

Comment: what seems to be the issue

Comment: I get undefined in console and the question is why?

Comment: Well it depends on where you're including your js. If it's included in head then it'll show undefined because the DOM is not loaded yet and if the script is set to `DOMContentLoaded` then it'll first wait for DOM to load then it'll not show any error in console. Have you tried something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best practice is to make you component call an API to get the course.

If it's not worth an API try to pass the `$course` as `attr` to your #app element. Then you can get your course with `getAttribute`

```
<div id="app" course="{{json_encode($course)}}"></div>
```

in vue.js:

```
document.getElementById('app').getAttribute('course')
```

Comment: Thanks. I can't do with API call because I can't get the id (param) from URL. The url is localhost/course/1.